# SQL Stored Procedure Validation in .NET Front End (Similar to Parse Option in SSMS)

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, .net-core, ssms

My front end application has a textarea where the user can enter the stored procedure. I want to validate the SP, similar to the option "Parse" in SSMS (Ctrl+F5).

Do we have any Library? or Function? to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects) or (SMO) in short

You would need to call

```
var options = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.Parser.ParseOptions
{
  BatchSeparator = "GO",
  CompatibilityLevel = Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.Common.DatabaseCompatibilityLevel.Version140 // depedning on the compatibilty level of your database.
};
var output = Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.Parser.Parser.Parse(inputString, options);

if(output.Errors.Any())
{
   // handle errors
}
```

This is the same code that is executed from SSMS when you execute the `Parse` command.

Why you shouldn't do this on a SQL server:

- SQL Injection
- Don't be dependent on a SQL Server
- Don't burn precious SQL Server CPU with things that are not ment for SQL server. (SQL server is an expensive part of your infrastructure running it in C# is way cheaper.)
- Use custom compatibility levels, independent of the SQL Server configuration.
- `options.TransactSqlVersion` could also be used if you want to parse for Azure SQL

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server, you can run a command which cause the next command not execute.

To do exactly what the `parse` button does, use

```
SET NOEXEC ON;
```

Any command after that, will not execute and only will be evaluated/compiled.
To go back to normal use below

```
SET NOEXEC OFF;
```

So to simplify your application and not using SMO, use below strategy:

Surround your query with `SET NOEXEC ON` and `SET NOEXEC OFF`

```
-- string yourSqlStatement  = "SET NOEXEC ON; " + textarea.Text + " SET NOEXEC OFF;"
-- execute the yourSqlStatement using your programming language
```

[SQL Server Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-noexec-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: This allows for SQL Injection. Example:  `SET NOEXEC OFF;  SELECT * FROM sys.Tables`

Comment: The OP is going to take a query from user and run it. Adding the SET NO EXEC, will not change the risk, and he should consider the injection in the first place when he wants to run the query entered by end-user.

Comment: although I do agree this is a risk but OP didn't specify and asks only to parse the input.

Comment: This scenario is when you are going to write a utility. The end-user may run DROP TABLE X, which is much bigger threat comparing sql injection.

Comment: @FLICKER, really good option. New thing, I learnt .

Comment: @VenkataramanR I'm glad you found it useful. I had used this years a go when I was writing my own Query Analyzer. :) Thanks for complement.

Answer (score 0):

One more option, you can think of is, create the procedure as temporary stored procedure, which is only for current session. Once you close the connection, the session is lost.

[msdn reference on CREATE PROCEDURE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> Local or global temporary procedures can be created by using one
> number sign (#) before procedure_name (#procedure_name) for local
> temporary procedures, and two number signs for global temporary
> procedures (##procedure_name). A local temporary procedure is visible
> only to the connection that created it and is dropped when that
> connection is closed. A global temporary procedure is available to all
> connections and is dropped at the end of the last session using the
> procedure. Temporary names cannot be specified for CLR procedures.
>
> The complete name for a procedure or a global temporary procedure,
> including ##, cannot exceed 128 characters. The complete name for a
> local temporary procedure, including #, cannot exceed 116 characters.

[Usage scenario of Temporary stored procedure](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/temporary-stored-procedures)

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE #TempProcedureName
AS
BEGIN
...
END
```

You will come to know of all the errors, similar to permanent stored procedure. But, the procedure is not actually created in the database. If the enduser actually wants to create procedure, post successful check, the procedure can be created permanently.