# SQL Server - Building table with column datatype as user input - how to validate the user input

Tags: sql-server, sql-injection, dynamic-sql

I have a stored procedure which creates tables based on inputs.

One of the inputs is the datatype of one of the columns in the table.

However, I am conscious that the user can input a string which is not a valid SQL datatype. This will result in either an error, or potentially injection.

Therefore, **I need to validate the input for valid SQL datatypes.**

**Is there a generic tool for validating a string to be a valid SQL data type?**

---

On the assumption that there is not, I go on.

I am aware of 3 valid formats for datatypes:

1. DataType
2. DataType(Number)
3. DataType(Number1, Number2)

**Am I missing any?**

---

Currently I am using:

```
sys.types
```

to get the list of valid SQL datatypes.

For case 1, I can check that the user input is in sys.types

For cases 2 and 3, I can get quite close by validating that the user input:

1. Is of the form sys.types + '(%)' AND
2. The value in the brackets is a number or two numbers, split by a single comma

Note that I have not cared to check for unacceptable inputs that fit in case 2 and 3, e.g. INT(40).

---

**If I validate that the input is in any of the three formats above:**

1. Are all datatypes still valid?
2. Am I protected from injection?

Comment: I suggest you don't accept SQL syntax from users. Accept their _choice_ referencing one of a predefined list of data types. The list is defined in your application. The user's input is only an ordinal number of which one they choose. That way the SQL syntax comes only from your application code, not from user input.

Comment: Are you doing this in pure sql or do you have a .net application in front of it?

Comment: @BillKarwin - Thanks for your suggestion. I could enforce that in SQL with a check that the input is from a given list.

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts There is not necessarily an app in front, although there may be in some use cases. I have to account for the case that there is not.

Comment: If you use an app you could use SMO like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62989202/639829